# Symfony2 (beta5) 1:M/M:1 in forms

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have entity "Creative" and Entity "Question"... When I had a ManyToMany relation from Creative to Question, I could easily do $builder->add('questions'), and it would grab all the questions and put them in a multiselect and insert into creative_question.  Well I need to have a new field (position) to creative_question, so I had to create a OneToMany / ManyToOne relation.  But when I add the field ($builder->add('creativeQuestions')), the multi-select is blank and it seems to be trying to query creative_question to populate it.. which is wrong.  I need to populate with Questions and insert those into creative_question.

Anyhow, here's my code:

```
## Creative.php

[...]

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Offer", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $offer;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CreativeQuestion", mappedBy="creative", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $creativeQuestions;

[...]
```

---

```
## CreativeQuestion.php

[...]

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Creative", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $creative;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Question", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $question;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
protected $pos;

[...]
```

---

```
## CreativeType.php

[...]

public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('title')
        ->add('description')
        ->add('body')
        ->add('script')
        ->add('creativeQuestions') // how do i populate list with "Questions" then insert into creative_question?
        ->add('active');
}

public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
{
    return array(
        'data_class' => 'JStout\MainBundle\Entity\Creative'
    );
}

[...]
```

---

```
## In My Controller:

 /**
 * @Extra\Route("/offer/{offerId}/creative", name="admin_offer_creative")
 * @Extra\Route("/offer/{offerId}/creative/{creativeId}", name="admin_offer_creative_edit")
 * @Extra\Template()
 */
public function creativeAction($offerId = null, $creativeId = null)
{
    // Get Offer
    $offer = $this->_getObject('Offer', $offerId);

    if (null === $offer->getId()) throw new NotFoundHttpException('The page you requested does not exist!');

    // Get Creative
    $creative = $this->_getObject('Creative', $creativeId);

    // Set offer to creative
    $creative->setOffer($offer);

    // Get form and handler
    $form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(new Form\CreativeType(), $creative);
    $formHandler = $this->get('form.handler')->create(new Form\CreativeHandler(), $form);

    [...]
}

protected function _getObject($entityName, $id = null)
{
    // Find object
    if (null !== $id) {
        if (!$object = $this->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager()->find('ZGOffersMainBundle:' . $entityName, $id)) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('The page you requested does not exist!');
        }

        return $object;
    }

    // Initialize new object
    $entityName = 'JStout\MainBundle\Entity\\' . $entityName;
    if (class_exists($entityName)) {
        return new $entityName();
    }

    throw new NotFoundHttpException('The page you requested does not exist!');
}

[...]
```

Again, what I need works when I remove CreativeQuestion and just do Question with a ManyToMany relation:

[image: working]

But, ideally I'd like to have the ability to (with jquery) add questions by selecting from a dropdown box, then drag/drop for positioning of the questions.  The jquery positioning is easy, I just don't know how to go about adding the questions how I want to.  If I can at least get the multiselect to work, then I can move forward, but I'm kind of stuck right now!

Anyone get this far yet with Symfony2 (beta5)?